# Recommended GPU for dual monitors on a 250w PSU? (Windows 10)

Tags: graphics-cards, video, multiple-monitors

I have a PC that currently has an old Asus 6600 GT graphics card in it, but there doesn't appear to be any Windows 10 drivers available for it.

Can anyone recommend a GPU that will run on a 250W power supply and provide dual monitor support?

Comment: Does the PC have a PCIe slot? The 6600 GT is old enough to possibly be an AGP slot so your motherboard might only have PCI and AGP.

Comment: Between the AGP and windows 10 requirement couldn't find any results.  Also 250w is very low.  Some AGP cards found on newegg had Windows 8 x64 support, you might get lucky, and force the windows 8 drivers in windows 10.  However, I wouldn't count on it.